# Best way to select a row after inserting it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm working on an iOS app using the Navigation based, CoreData template. 
I would like to **select and "scroll to visible" a row after it was inserted into the table view**. Ideally i'd like to select it, deselect it and select it again, in order to get a kind of flashing effect.

As i am using the method, that the template provaides, namely:

```
#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;


    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{


    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

i am a bit confused and don't know, where to put that selection code.
If i put a
 `[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:<#(NSIndexPath *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#> scrollPosition:<#(UITableViewScrollPosition)#>]`
 into
`- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller`,
it selects the row, but deselects it immediately and the scrolling doesn't behave as it should either.

Answer (score 3):

in method `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`
change this section:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
   [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
   insertedIndexPath = newIndexPath; //remember for selection
break;
```

and add method from UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:insertedIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

remember to add insertedIndexPath variable.

Comment: Thank you. But i sporadically get an error with this. `Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (1) beyond bounds (1) for section (3). with userInfo (null)`. It also sometimes selects the wrong row. Is there another way maybe?

Comment: do you use sections that can be collapsed (hide rows)? if yes then you must check if section to that you insert new row is showing rows, if not then don't execute anything in `case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:` or you will get this error, other thing: check if you have insertRowsAtIndexPaths before scrollToRowAtIndexPath, if I call scroll before insert then I get this error too

Comment: This works beautifully, except when the table doesn't actually need to scroll.  For example, if the table is scrolled to the top already, and the new row inserted is at the top, then scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation is never called.  Telling the tableview to select the row in controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath: doesn't work either, because the tableview hasn't actually updated yet.  A possible workaround may be checking in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath to see if the cell being displayed should be selected, but isn't.

Comment: To update, I could not make this work in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, so I ended up scrapping setting the selection in scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation and simply used performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: to run a method to set the selection and scroll position after everything has finished updating.

Answer (score 3):

I solved similar problem. I inserted item to beginning of Table and I wanted to select it just right after.

Step 1. - Create a switch to keep state if it shall select first row

```
@implementation MyTableViewController {
    BOOL _selectFirstRow;
}
```

Step 2. - Switch it to YES while inserting

```
- (void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            _selectFirstRow = YES;
            break;
```

Step 3. - Create a method to select first row

```
- (void) selectFirstTableRow
{
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
                                animated:YES
                          scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

Step 4. - Call the method to select row right after table is updated

```
- (void) controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    if (_selectFirstRow) {
        [self selectFirstTableRow];
        _selectFirstRow = NO;
    }
}
```

That's all folks .. if you want select different row, store newIndexPath in class parameter too. That's all. I hope it will help you. Cia!

Answer (score 2):

Mostly same answer as above but with corrected placement of when to call scrollToRowAtIndexPath

in method `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`
change this section:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
   [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   //save new index path into your own ivar
   self.newlyInsertIndex = newIndexPath
break;
```

*if using boiler plate FRC code*, cannot scroll to newly inserted index until table updates finished

Do this in method `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:`

```
    if (!self.changeIsUserDriven){

         [self.tableView endUpdates];

        if (self.newlyInsertedIndex){
            //ScrollPositionNone == use least amount of effort to show cell
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.newlyInsertedIndex  
            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
            //cleanup
            self.newlyInsertedIndex = Nil;
        }
    }
```

and add method from UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:insertedIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

remember to add newlyInsertedIndex ivar

Answer (score 0):

This all did not work for me. What I did was:

- when I create a new object, I remember it in an instance variable `_newInstance`
- when the object is saved or the creation cancelled, I clear it: `_newInstance = nil;`
- in `controllerDidChangeObject` I select the row:

  ```
  - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    if (_newObject) {
      NSIndexPath *ip = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:_newObject];
      [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:YES
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    }
  }
  ```